# How to get Dropdownlist value on HTML Table Cell in a Row using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem in getting the value of dropdownlist on HTML table. Below is my sample html and javascript.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="select1" onchange="getValue(this.value)">
      <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="val1">value 1</option>
      <option value="val2">value 2</option>
      <option value="val3">value 3</option>
</select>
</td>
 <td id="row-1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <select id="select2" onchange="getValue(this.value)">
      <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="val1">value 1</option>
      <option value="val2">value 2</option>
      <option value="val3">value 3</option>
</select>
</td>
 <td id="row-2"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getValue(data)
    {
     var myDiv = document.getElementById( "row-1" );
     myDiv.innerHTML = data;
 }
</script>
```

Each row has a unique td id. example:row-1, row-2 .. and so on.

When selecting an item on the dropdown, I want to display the dropdown value in each row inside the row cell. How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>

        <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select id="select1" onchange="getValue(this)">
              <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
              <option value="val1">value 1</option>
              <option value="val2">value 2</option>
              <option value="val3">value 3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
         <td id="select1-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
           <select id="select2" onchange="getValue(this)">
              <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
              <option value="val1">value 1</option>
              <option value="val2">value 2</option>
              <option value="val3">value 3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
         <td id="select2-value"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function getValue(data)
            {
             var myDiv = document.getElementById( data.id + '-value' );
             myDiv.innerHTML = data.value;
         }
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="select1">
      <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="val1">value 1</option>
      <option value="val2">value 2</option>
      <option value="val3">value 3</option>
</select>
</td>
 <td id="row-1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <select id="select2">
      <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="val1">value 1</option>
      <option value="val2">value 2</option>
      <option value="val3">value 3</option>
</select>
</td>
 <td id="row-2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
$('select').change(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.parent().siblings('td[id^=row-]').html($this.val());
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y965rkba/).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object:

```
onchange="getValue(this)"
```

Then, `source.parentNode` is the `<td>`, and `source.parentNode.nextSibling` is the adjacent `<td>`

```
function getValue(source) {
     source.parentNode.nextSibling.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```